# Python Pandas - Search for value in column and append to new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in python with an update column containing text. In each row of this column there is a value between parenthesis that I want to grab and place in a new column.

So if it says "Day To Day (Hand) - Bembry did not play" I want to take Hand and add it to a new column named Injury in the same df

See the code below:

```
display(df.dtypes)

Team      object
Date      object
Update    object
dtype: object

display(df.head())
    Team    Date    Update
0   Atlanta Hawks   Fri, Feb 7, 2020    Day To Day (Hand) - Bembry did not play in Fri...
1   Atlanta Hawks   Sat, Feb 8, 2020    Out (Right Calcaneus) - Capela is out for Sund...
2   Atlanta Hawks   Sat, Feb 8, 2020    Day To Day (Calf) - Fernando is probable for S...
3   Atlanta Hawks   Sat, Feb 8, 2020    Day To Day (Right Knee) - Graham is probable f...
4   Atlanta Hawks   Sat, Feb 8, 2020    Day To Day (Left Ankle) - Hunter is questionab...
```

Would someone be able to point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
df["Injury"] = df["Update"].apply(lambda x: x[x.find("(") + 1 : x.find(")")])
```

What `.apply` does is it takes the "Update" column and runs each value inside through a function, and returns the result. In this case that function finds the text between the parentheses. Then you can just set the new column to that returned value.

Comment: You should avoid using ```.apply(...)```: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54432584/11610186

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
df["Injury"]=df["Update"].str.extract(r"[(]([^)]*)[)]")
```

It will return the content of first encountered square brackets inside of `Update` column.

Ref: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html

If you wish to have more than one per line - consider using `pd.Series.extractall(...)`